# Create synonym between "mushroom" and "mycology

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

I think a user with sufficient rep on the [mycology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mycology) tag (or a mod) should create the synonym [mushroom](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mushroom) --> [mycology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mycology) (i.e. [mycology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mycology) as the main tag). [fungi](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fungi) and [fungus](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fungus) are already synonyms, but mushroom is not, which is rather inconsistent. I suspect that 'mushroom' has crept into some questions over time, and currently 26 questions are using the tag (vs. 106 using 'mycology').

Comment: I created the synonym.

Comment: @Chris Since quite few regular visitors of the site have >5 rep on 'mycology' I suspect that mods have to create this on you own - enough synonym voting will probably take a long time.

Comment: Good point, I did exactly that.